# Sharepoint 2013 PushNotification for iOS/Android

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Is there a way can we send Push Notification to iOS/android app which consumes my share point site ( say when an item is updated in a SharePoint 2013 List).

I am aware that it can be implemented for Windows phone. Anyways to do the same in iOS/Android?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to consider your mobile applications and your backend
>   different concerns. For your apps it does not matter what is running
>   in the backend.
>
> But what matters is that each of the platforms has its own
>   notification system, see:
>
> Android: [An Overview of Remote Notifications in Xamarin.Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/remote_notifications_in_ios/)
>
> iOS: [Push Notifications in iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/remote_notifications_in_ios/)
>
> Beside the platform-spefific configuration of certificates etc

I hope you will get idea from given references..!